# scanf character input/output

Tags: c

scanf not working as expected with a normal input character

So I was just trying out the scanf() and a normal input/output of this function. I know that I had to leave a space before the input character and the operand% so my code is as below. Somehow I don't understand why whatever the input I inserted the output remains 0.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
  char c ;

  scanf(" %c",&c);
  printf("%c",c);

  return 0;
  }
```

I was expecting the output will be whatever the character I insert. For example, insert an "A" via keyboard and the output will be exactly an "A".

---

I'm using a vim environment to edit my code, but I found that if I run this code on codeblocks it works. What's the difference?

Comment: Works [here](https://ideone.com/WOpItO)

Comment: I declared only a char data type, how would I confirm the return value of scanf()?

Comment: I'm using a vim environment to edit my code, but I found that if I run this code on codeblocks it works. What's the difference?

Comment: It should work. The only thing is that you can make this change: `scanf(" %c",&c);`--> `if (scanf(" %c",&c) != 1) printf("svanf error\n";`

Comment: It doesn't matter how you edit your code. How are you running it?

Comment: How/where is the output o? Is there a letter "0" printed? Is the return value of your program 0? Because that is definitly the case, I just wonder whether this is what you mean. Or is no output what you mean by "0"?

Comment: Do as 4386427 recommends, also init your character to e.g. `'#'`. See what happens.

Comment: I don't understand where did you get that you need to put a space in front of `%c`.  Anyway, instead of printing `c` with `%c`, do it with `%d` in order to see which character did you get, as the char can be a control character, so you will not see it, or mistakenly confound it the control effector you receive.

Comment: BTW I run your program on the terminal, I input an `A` followed by a `Return` and I get an `A` on output.

Comment: When working in *vim*, are you sure you actually even run the program? Maybe you are just building it and seeing successful build exit code 0?

Comment: its working fine dude, just ran it on codeblocks.

Answer (score 4):

It appears you are not providing any non-whitespace (which are eaten away by th space in the format string, including newlines) characters (or perhaps nothing at all) from standard input. If this happens, `scanf` will fail to parse a char and leaves `c` uninitialized.

Using uninitialized variable is is *Undefined Beheavior*, so in theory *anything* could happen. In practice, from your description, it sounds like memory reserved for `c` happens to have byte value 0, which is unprintable character, so `printf` prints something else (maybe `/0`, maybe nothing). And then the environment (*vim*) might show you the program exit code, also 0 here (assuming the Undefined Behavior doesn' cause your program to crash).

To fix this, check return value of `scanf`:

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
   char c ;

   int r = scanf(" %c",&c);
   if (r==1) {
      // Always print something and add newline
      // to be sure we see some output always.
      printf("c='%c'\n",c);
   } else {
      printf("scanf error: %d\n", r);
      // If r==-1, errno variable tells what error was
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

---

Practical hint: To provide standard input when there is no terminal (so you can't type the input), you can pipe something:

```
echo A | ./thisprogram
```

Comment: Why do you suspect the program is being run from `vim` ???  This is the most strange thing I've read.  Can you explain how/why do you suspect that?

Comment: @LuisColorado That is pretty much implied by OPs comment about how it doesn't work when editing in *vim*, but works when run under Code::Blocks.

Comment: The OP says he _uses_ `vim` **for editing the source file**, not that he is running that example through `vim`.  Anyway, filtering some part of the input file through the program or running it from `:!` will use stdin and stdout from/to the buffer, or the terminal, so he will have standard input and output anyway.  In unix, it's almost impossible to run a program without stdin or stdout, despite being able to see them can be difficult sometimes.

Comment: @LuisColorado Mm, yeah (now that I tested :! myself). Having stdin be empty (or whitespace-only eaten away by the space in question code scanf format string would produce the same effect) is easy though. It would be necessary to know just how OP is running the code in the *vim* scenario.

Comment: Yeah, the OP doesn't check for input errors, but that's not the issue.  The OP describes perfectly the input he had tested (single `A` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and that input must work with the program he posts.

Comment: Yesh, but apparently nothing is shown. So checking for input errors is the first thing to check... Works/does not work for same code is usually an environment issue. Now I edited this so something visible is printed always, because that is another half of figuring out what is happening.

Comment: nothing is shown can be for multiple reasons, not only because of running the program from vi (this is the most rare case, i think)  The OP has not issued a `\n` after the character, so probably the prompt (if he has installed one of the custom prompts from many linux distributions) overwrote it.  Who knows exactly what happened?  It's also possible that the OP doesn't recognise his `A` letter, and it's indeed there.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to run your program (exactly as it appears in your question)

## pru.c

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
  char c ;

  scanf(" %c",&c);
  printf("%c",c);

  return 0;
  }
```

and with the input you posted in your question (just `A` plus <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and got the following result:

```
$ cc pru.c
$ ./a.out
A
A$ _
```

which is exactly the expected output.  So the problem must be in another place, or you have a completely different scenario and need to provide more information.

I tested this on a PC (Intel Core Duo) with FreeBSD 12.0/CLANG compiler.  (here `$` is the unix prompt and `_` is the cursor after the run)  And of course, the program has been edited with `vi(1)` (this has no impact on the result).

## Edit

Try to change

```
  printf("%c",c);
```

by this

```
  printf("0x%02x, [%c]\n",c,c);
```

so, you'll get an hex dump of the character just input, and also its representation as printed.  The `\n` at the end is to ensure your shell prompt is not eating (overwriting) the last line output of your program (mostly if you have changed the prompt variable `PS1`) hidding the printed char.

That should produce (on your posted input) the following output:

```
$ cc pru.c                <--- compilation of new pru.c
$ ./a.out                 <--- default name for your program executable.
A                         <--- this is your input (followed by <return>)
0x41, [A]                 <--- this should be your program output.
$ _                       <--- prompt (and cursor) after your program execution
```